# How to merge all PDF's in a directory with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, merge, ghostscript

How can I read the files contained in the directory d:\ with `batchscript` not one by one files like that. I have tried the following:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dColorImageResolution=90 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=d:\d\koran.pdf *d:\a\01.pdf d:\a\02.pdf d:\a\03.pdf d:\a\04.pdf d:\a\05.pdf d:\a\06.pdf d:\a\07.pdf d:\a\08.pdf d:\a\09.pdf d:\a\10.pdf d:\a\11.pdf d:\a\12.pdf d:\a\13.pdf d:\a\14.pdf d:\a\15.pdf d:\a\16.pdf d:\a\17.pdf d:\a\18.pdf d:\a\19.pdf d:\a\20.pdf d:\a\21.pdf d:\a\22.pdf d:\a\23.pdf d:\a\24.pdf*

exit
```

Answer (score 5):

Ghostscript doesn't 'merge' PDF files. It creates new PDF files by interpreting the contents of its input, this is not the same thing. You should read the documentation [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

You haven't said what the problem is with the command you have tried, its going to be hard to help you if you don't do that.

The most likely problem is that you have put * characters at the start and end of the input filenames. Ghostscript itself doesn't match wildcards, it expects you to tell it each file you want to process individually. So in order to process a directory of files is to first get a list of all the files, and then tell Ghostscritp to use each of those files in turn.

You can use the Ghostscript @filename syntax (documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/Use.htm#Options))to tell Ghostscript to use the contents of a file as if it were the command line.

So all you need to do is come up with a shell script which will write the filenames from a folder into a file. That's not a Ghostscript question, and depends totally on the operating system you are using.

For Windows something like:

```
dir /B *.pdf >> files.txt
gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pdf @files.txt
del files.txt
```

**might** be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Merge is the term used by PDFCreator etc. Anyways this script is more user friendly than current version of PDFCreator to merge pdf files!

Comment: PDFCreator isn't anything to do with the Ghostscript developers, and we can't be held responsible for their mis-information :-)

Comment: I have to put the "@files.txt" parameter in double quotes in Windows 11, GhostScript 9.55.0, powershell console.

Comment: I can't think why but since my hardware won't run Windows 11 I'll have to take your word for it.

Comment: With powershell on  windows 10:  `Get-ChildItem -Path D:\*.pdf -name | out-file files.txt` and  `gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=D:/out.pdf "@files.txt"`

Comment: This only works without special characters and blanks in file names.

Answer (score -1):

I could not make it work using "files.txt" but I am using this and everything works just fine.

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="out.pdf" (Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.pdf)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can execute like below:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf *.pdf
```

Reference:

https://gist.github.com/moaazsidat/b94185e9cfdba9e3cfb5bc90407e6397

Comment: This did not work for me with GhostScript 9.55.0 in Windows 11 command console (powershell). The github reference link's content implies that the wild card method does not work and provides good alternative methods (without wild card)